# SQL: Filter XML retrieving using xpath

Tags: sql, xml, xpath

I have documents table, each row has a XML column `Document`:

```
<Document>
   <Good GroupId="..."/>
   <Good GroupId="..."/>
   ...
</Document>
```

I also have temp table with subset of `GroupId` values:

```
DECLARE @Groups TABLE (groupId VARCHAR(MAX));
```

Next, I wrote a `select` query to documents table, goal - retrieve XML from `Document`:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT CAST(Document.data as XML)).query('/Document/Good') AS Goods
FROM 
    Documents as Document
JOIN 
    @Numbers n ON n.number = Document.number
WHERE
    Document.type = @type
    --FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('Documents')
```

As a result, in column `Goods` I got all `Good` items for each `Document`

**Task**:

In step 3, I need filter `Good` elements by `GroupId` attribute (using `@Groups`) - I need all `Good` for which `GroupId` value is not contained in `@Groups`

Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't `Document` an `XML` datatype column? Why is `GroupId` in `@Groups` of type `VARCHAR(MAX)` ?? The `Id` parts seems to indicate an *identifier*, which most often is an `INT` or `BIGINT` - but definitely not a 2 GB large `Varchar(max)`

Comment: Historically. No time for refactoring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `CROSS APPLY` to extract the attribute values from the XML

Need to use `LEFT JOIN` to find Goods in XML but not in @Goods table.

Here is the SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6b9e/5

```
SELECT G.value('@GroupId', 'varchar(max)') FROM
(
SELECT
    CAST(Document.data as XML) AS Goods
FROM 
    Documents as Document
WHERE type = 1
) T
CROSS APPLY T.Goods.nodes('Document/Good') D(G)
LEFT JOIN @Groups GS
ON G.value('@GroupId', 'varchar(max)') = GS.groupId
WHERE GS.groupId IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's what I need exactly.